# How to group strings based on similarities in the string

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-formula

I have a splunk query that produces a summarises errors by frequency

```
index="pc_1" LogLevel=ERROR 
   | eval Message=split(_raw,"|") 
   | stats count(LogLevel) as Frequency by Message 
   | sort -Frequency
```

This produces results in the form

| Message | Frquency |
| --- | --- |
| No such user | 137 |
| unable to deliver mail to example@email.com: Unable to reach server | 70 |
| unable to deliver mail to example1@email.com: Unable to reach server | 43 |
| unable to authenticate user 3456 | 8 |
| unable to deliver mail to example2@email.com: Unable to reach server | 6 |
| unable to authenticate user 2321 | 5 |
| unable to authenticate user 13321 | 3 |
| ... | . |
| ... | . |
| ... | . |
| unable to deliver mail to examplen@email.com: Unable to reach server | 1 |

As you can notice in the results produced, some similar errors are  being split based on difference in ids of users emails, and machine ids.
I am looking for a way I can group this based on similarities in strings. Currently what I am using is the replace the strings with a common regexp and then find the frequency

```
index="pc_1" LogLevel=ERROR 
   | eval Message=split(_raw,"|")

   | eval Message=replace("unable to deliver mail to (.)* Unable to reach server", "unable to deliver mail to [email]: Unable to reach server")
   | eval Message=replace("unable to authenticate user \d+", "unable to authenticate user [userId]")

   | stats count(LogLevel) as Frequency by Message 
   | sort -Frequency
```

This approach works but is quite cumbersome as there are a number of different types of errors and if this solution is to be implemented then it require going through each error and developing a regular expression for each.

Is there a way this can be improved with a query that can summarize this error more effectively?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this - your logs should be storing the original template-string, not just the _formatted_ message string.

Comment: @Dai What I am trying to achieve is that in the dashboard, users can view the number of each type of error occurring. The logs will not be changed only that the grouping looks misleading. If user1 experiences an error and user2 experiences the same error, then this errors should be counted in the same group

Comment: Right, that's my point - but you shouldn't need a regex for this. You _should_ be able to simply group by just the original template string and *that's all you need to do* (before sorting by `-Frequency`, of course)

Comment: @Dai thats what I am trying to find, is there a way I can group this without using a RegExp?

Comment: The important thing is: **are you processing Rendered Logs or are you processing structured logs?**

Comment: @Dai the logs are pipe `|` separated logs. I extract the log strings as illustrated above. The only challenge is just in grouping the errors.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though - are these rendered logs - or structured logs? If they're rendered, is there a _good reason_ for that? You should only ever be using structured logs with Splunk or you'll experience nothing but pain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228200/discussion-between-owen-kelvin-and-dai).

Comment: Perhaps the `cluster` command will help.  It groups like messages together.

Comment: @RichG thanks for the advice. will give it a try and get back

Comment: @RichG cluster worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for posterity:

Perhaps the `cluster` command will help. It groups like messages together.